# FreeFileSync does not move files within the backup folder

Tags: backup, sync

I am using FreeFileSync to synchronise my files. However, I get the impression if I move files within my original folder and synchronise my original folder with my backup folder, that the moved files are copied to the new location and the old files at the old location in the backup are deleted. Instead I would like FreeFileSync to just move the file within the backup folder and skip the copying and deleting. It is said that FreeFileSnyc is able to do that and I ticket the option in the synchronisation settings, but FreeFileSync is not acting on it. What do I have to do?

My settings are (though in German, but the buttons should be still at the same positions ;-)):

[image]

Comment: You might have selected 'Mirror' option in Sync settings. This will create an exact mirror of Left Side on Right Side so it will delete the files on Right that do not exist in the same location on Left. Please check.

Comment: @pat2015: No, please check my settings in the edited question.

Comment: In your settings it looks like you have chosen 'Delete if the Item exists on Right only' the very last Icon on right side. As you move the files on Left the same items on Right get affected by this rule. Set it to 'Do Nothing'

Comment: @pat2015: When I do this, the box "Detect moved files" (="Verschobene Dateien erkennen") is grey instead of black...

Comment: What file system your folders are on? FAT/NTFS?  With original settings, after comparison do you see a Move Icon or Delete Icon on affected Moved files?

Comment: @pat2015: I am using ext4 as file system (Linux). I have seen that before and I have seen it again at some point recently, but most of the time not - I have no idea what the reason is.

Answer (score 0):

On the first synchronization of a folder pair (configured as shown on your screenshot), "moved" files will be created/deleted, as you say. A database will also be created in each folder (your "original" and "backup" folder) - "sync.ffs_db".

[Create Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbklO.png)

If you then move around files in your original folder (assuming it's shown to the left in the Program GUI) after the database is created, and run a "compare", the files will be listed as one create and one delete (as before). However the synchronization dialogue box will indicate that the file will actually be moved and no data copied between sync folders

[Move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQTOv.png)

> Note: The information in the dialogue box is also listed in lower right corner
>
> Note: A database should be created when you selected "Detect Moved files" = "Verschobene Dateien erkennen"

Tested on Free File Sync Version 6.10